# rewrite directory to a php file with get parameter

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to redirect the user from

```
localhost/test/Mj4sD
```

to

```
localhost/test/short.php?url=Mj4sD
```

whereas Mj4sd is pattern of 5 letters (lowercase, uppercase, number).
   My current configuration:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/test/[A-Za-z][0-9]{0,5}$ /test/short.php?url=$1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must to change your `RewriteRule` to:

```
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ ./short.php?url=$1
```

Comment: The code is very simple(convert path to get request). Why the code is ambiguous for you? @AmitGaud

Comment: Because you haven't explain anything in that, a good answer always have some explanation so that it can be used in future also and user does not have to read question each time. @mshomali

Comment: @mshomali Your answer does not fulfill the exact requirement. **1.** `\w+` also includes `_` in them which is not at all required. **2.** OP want to capture everything after `/test/` but in your answer you captured whole request.

Comment: @mshomali Do you what this expression mean `[A-Za-z][0-9]{0,5}` ? This mean match a single character between `A-Z` or `a-z` and then five digits.  It should be combined `([A-Za-z0-9]{0,5})` like this.